# Transparent Depth and Transparent Node not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, shaders

I am trying to create a shader that renders visible when looking at it from behind another invisible object, and vice versa. However, when the object is supposed to be invisible, it renders a black artifact in it's place. Is there any way to get rid of this and simply keep it transparent?

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6eRZ.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the issue you're having is ***due to a circular dependency***.  You're counting the number of *Transparent Shaders* the ray is passing through, ***but what happens when the material that that number depends on is a Transparency itself?***  I believe that's why Blender creates a Null shader.

You can do something similar with a *Glass Transmission Shader* set to IOR of 1.0 for your "transparent window" thingy.  Disable everything but Camera in the *Cycles Setting*:

[image]

Then instead of *Transparent Depth*, just use the *Transmission Depth* input for your object:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have a question that I feel is a bit relevant to the discussions here. I wonder could you please take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101589/how-to-render-depth-or-surface-normal-maps-that-properly-reflect-details-of-3d-s)? I basically want to render depth maps or surface Normals by somehow ignoring the transparent materials. Do you think that's possible?